# How do i store data for HTML for file://

Tags: javascript, html, file, cookies, local-storage

so I wanted to store a cookie for light mode and dark mode inside a html file in file://, NOT a webpage. [file:// path, not a webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMA3Z.png)

but then I learnt that cookies don't actually work on file:// (or at least on chrome).
so I googled and learnt about local storage, but that too does not work....

so I wanted to know is there any other way of storing data even on a file:// path?

thank you

Comment: Have you tried session storage as well?

Comment: i don't know if that works or not. most probably it might not. im not sure

Comment: Yeah. I just tried that and it didn't work. But I was able to store them inside the Shared storage and I think it preserves the data even after closing the whole browser .You can read it from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Shared_Storage_API). But It only support edge , chrome and opera